# how to prevent overfitting in reinforced learning with vgg16

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, overfitting-underfitting

I'm trying to train a model to recognize facial expressions, so basically a classification problem with 7 classes:

```
img_size=48
batch_size=64
datagen_train=ImageDataGenerator(       rotation_range=15,
                                        width_shift_range=0.15,
                                        height_shift_range=0.15,
                                        shear_range=0.15,
                                        zoom_range=0.15,
                                        horizontal_flip=True,
                                        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
                                    )
train_generator=datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
   train_path,
    target_size=(img_size,img_size),
    # color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',   
    shuffle=True
)

datagen_validation=ImageDataGenerator( horizontal_flip=True,  preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
validation_generator=datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
   valid_path,
    target_size=(img_size,img_size),
    # color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',   
    shuffle=True,
)
```

I'm using ImageDataGenerator and I did my model with VGG16 no head transfer learning like so :

```
ptm = PretrainedModel(
    input_shape=[48,48,3],
    weights='imagenet',
    include_top=False)

x = Flatten()(ptm.output)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)


x = Dense(7, activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='random_uniform', bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), name='predictions')(x)

opt=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001)
model = Model(inputs=ptm.input, outputs=x)
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer=opt,
  metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.summary()
```

I used optimizers and early stopping and ran 100 epochs :

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    min_delta=0.00005,
    patience=11,
    verbose=1,
    restore_best_weights=True,
)

lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    factor=0.5,
    patience=7,
    min_lr=1e-7,
    verbose=1,
)

callbacks = [
    early_stopping,
    lr_scheduler,
]
```

and after 61 epochs I had an early stop, and I got a decent accuracy, but the val_accuracy was very low compared to it:

```
loss: 0.6081 - accuracy: 0.7910 - val_loss: 1.4658 - val_accuracy: 0.5608
```

any suggestions on how I can fix this overfitting? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your validation generator remove `horizontal_flip=True` and set `shuffle=False`. Also, you have the code

```
validation_generator=datagen_train.flow_from_directory( etc
```

You want to change it to

```
validation_generator=datagen_validation.flow_from_directory(etc
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try that and let you know, may I have an explanation why this would work?

Comment: I applied your fix, the result is still the same :(